# is UML class diagram necessary to design the UI?

Tags: user-interface, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to design a UI based on Use cases, activity diagrams and sequence diagrams. is it necessary to design the Class diagrams for the UI design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No diagrams are needed to write the code, but it would make the life hell for a 3rd person to understand the application and work on it.

As famous English proverb, images are better than 1000 words. UML diagrams are one of the easy  and standard ways to document the application architecture.

If you are building the application for your own sake, then it might be an excuse not to use UML otherwise I would suggest to have the required UML diagrams (Class diagrams, sequence diagrams and Entity relationship diagrams, if applicable (Datamodel)).

Comment: in my part the data model is not so important, since i am working on the system features and intraction design. do you still think its necessary?

Comment: If you do not have database then ER diagrams are not necessary. In the post, I was about to write ER diagrams if applicable

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer, and will add that UML diagrams are a form of documentation. As such, they are only of use if there is an intended recipient - could be another team, or yourself at some point in the future (remember, most coding work is maintenance), or a design authority if you need to get approval of your design before you write the code.

This is assuming you're not intending to do code generation from your model, which EA is eminently able to do (but which I personally think is a bad idea).

Comment: since in my case i aimed at improving a running system. i think it can help to improve the UI and user interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Although, there are not always required, UML diagrams do help a third party to understand your code. The whole process of implementing a UML digram to code could make your debugging easier as well, as you mentioned above you will be looking at 'digram' rather than plane code.